# how to change menu items display name in java netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am trying to switch between two languages in my application
, I want to know the way to access to menu items text and there actions text to change it when switch language

Comment: jMenuItem.setText("TEXT HERE");?

Comment: Are you using swing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing with NetBeans, you can do like this to add events:

[image]

Then in the source you will have a function like this:

```
private void jMenuItem1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jMenuItem1.setText("TEST"); //you can change the MenuItem text
}
```